# How to make object transparented when player approaches them based on their distance?

Tags: game-engine, transparency

I have an horror game project, and I want to make an object disappear when player gets near them.

Of course, the disappeared object needs to have opacity step based on player's distance to the object.

So, Is there is anyway to make an object slowly disappear when player approaches them based on their distance? (Phyton suggestion allowed)

Comment: You can do this in a node shader using the camera node and extracting the Z distance. No idea if this is faster than a python solution or not, but it will work differently for really large objects (ie close parts of a big object are transparent while far parts are not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** In your material active (enable, check) **Transparency checkbox**:

[image: set material]

**2.** **Select** the desire **object**

**3.** In **logic editor**, add an always sensor connected to a pyton controller:
[image]

**4.** script.py

```
from bge import logic
own = logic.getCurrentController().owner
player = logic.getCurrentScene().objects['Cube']
distance = own.getDistanceTo(player)
#if distance 
print('distance : ', distance*0.02)
if distance * 0.04 < 1:
    own.meshes[0].materials[0].alpha = distance * 0.04
    print('alpha : ', own.meshes[0].materials[0].alpha)
```

**Related**

[Python API (bge object material)](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/search.html?q=bge+object+material)

[bge.types.KX_BlenderMaterial.alpha](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.types.KX_BlenderMaterial.html?highlight=blendermaterial#bge.types.KX_BlenderMaterial.alpha)

[image]

Comment: Glad to help :P